# How to handle navigation of pages in Puppeteer UI Automation code

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, puppeteer, chai

Here's the automation code for the web application for user name and password:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const expect = require('chai').expect;

describe("User Login",()=>{
    
    let browser;
    let page;

    before(async function(){
        browser = await puppeteer.launch({
            headless:false,
            slowMo:100
        });
        page = await browser.newPage();
        await page.goto('https://www.test.com');
        await page.waitForSelector('input[name=UserName]');

    });

    it("Successful login",async()=>{
        await page.type('input[name=UserName]', 'test', {delay: 20});
        await page.type('input[name=Password]', 'test', {delay: 20});
        const button = await page.$('input[id=submitCredentials]');
        await button.click();
              
        //await page.waitForSelector('.item-group security-question');
    });

    after(async function(){
        await browser.close();
    })
});
```

Once the login is successful the application navigates to a different page, I cannot find a way to get the page object in puppeteer which I can use to validate if the login is successful or not.

Comment: Are you mean the application open new tab or just navigate to new page in current tab?

Comment: In the current tab itself just navigating to a different URL.

Answer (score 0):

I did find a solution to the problem at: [Codota](https://www.codota.com/code/javascript/functions/puppeteer/Page/waitForNavigation)

Here's the modified code :

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const expect = require('chai').expect;

describe("User Login",()=>{
    
    let browser;
    let page;

    before(async function(){
        browser = await puppeteer.launch({
            headless:false,
            slowMo:100
        });
        page = await browser.newPage();
        await page.goto('https://www.test.com');
        await page.waitForSelector('input[name=UserName]');

    });

    it("Successful login",async()=>{
        await page.type('input[name=UserName]', 'test', {delay: 20});
        await page.type('input[name=Password]', 'test', {delay: 20});
        const button = await page.$('input[id=submitCredentials]');
        const navigationPromise = page.waitForNavigation();
        await button.click();
        await navigationPromise;
        await page.waitForSelector('div[class="item-group security-question"]');
        const question = await page.$eval('input[id=QuestionId]', element => element.textContent);
        expect(question).to.be.not.null;
    });

    after(async function(){
        await browser.close();
    })
});
```